# Are there any issues when using a single NVIDIA GPU in a dual boot system?

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, gpu

Apparently using a GPU with a virtual environment is not possible or at least not convenient.

So my next question is, if I dual boot a windows 10 machine with ubuntu, and the machine has one NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 GPU, will I be able to use this in both OS? (not at the same time, of course!)

And are there any issues that I should be aware while doing this?

Comment: No there are no "issues". You are using one OS at a time.

Comment: A common suggestion when dual booting Windows is disabling fast startup because otherwise Windows will hibernate when you click shutdown, leaving some devices in a sort of "deep sleep" state instead of properly powering them off. I've mostly heard about this problem with USB devices though, not graphics cards.

Comment: The only issue would be having the right settings in Ubuntu for the card.  Have been issues with black screen when installing/booting, but there are ways of fixing them.  Would google the card with ubuntu so you would know if any issues and how to fix.  This is only for some GPUs, others will work right out of the box.  Just something to be aware of.